# NaN error: duedate counter works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, timer

Hello I have this code that works in chrome, but doesn't work for some reason in Firefox I get `NaN` for the outputs of the values. I read something about the `Math` functions have errors.

- Also online I saw that `document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;` has some troubles in Firefox so maybe I'm doing something wrong with this?
- So the ultimate question is how to get this to work in Firefox??

```html
 

   <div id="dueDate-counter">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>days</td>
       <td>hrs</td>
       <td>mns</td>
       <td>secs</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="days"></td>
       <td id="hours"></td>
       <td id="minutes"></td>
       <td id="seconds"></td>
      </tr>

     </table> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
      function countdown() {
       var now = new Date();
       var eventDate = new Date("<%= reservation.due_date %>");
       <%= puts "here is reservation !!!!!!!" %>;
       <%= puts "#{reservation.due_date}" %>;
       var currentTime = now.getTime();
       var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

       var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

       var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
       var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
       var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
       var d = Math.floor(h / 24);

       h %= 24;
       m %= 60;
       s %= 60;

       h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
       m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
       s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

       document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
       document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

       document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
       document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
       document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;

        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
         }

        countdown();

     </script>

    </div>
```

This is what my counter looks like with the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If `new Date("<%= reservation.due_date %>")` is an invalid date then `eventDate.getTime()` will be `NaN`, and in turn all of your other calculations will produce `NaN`. I tested your code with a valid date string in place of `<%= reservation.due_date %>` and it worked.

Comment: what could make the date invalid?  it comes out as `2017-02-10 00:41:00 UTC`.

Comment: Hard-coding that value within your function as `new Date("2017-02-10 00:41:00 UTC")` and removing the two `<%= puts...` lines resulting in a working counter when I tried it in Chrome.

Comment: okay so i noticed you said chrome and realized that this error is happening in firefox